# Continue getting error with WebGL build with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

I'm new to Unity, I made a little game with Unity 2D after following some tutorials. Now I want to publish a WebGL build but I got this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherMiddleware/<>c__DisplayClass13_0:<CheckProgress>b__0 (UnityEngine.AsyncOperation) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/Redux/Middleware.cs:187)
UnityEngine.AsyncOperation:InvokeCompletionEvent ()
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: I got the error above from the Unity Editor, now I go directly on Unity play to load the build and that works, but don't understand why don't go from Unity Editor.

Comment: New user and I'm here for the same issue. I know today Unity is closing its collaborate feature to push Plastic SCM instead. Maybe there are a series of changes going on which are causing this. Thanks for the heads up about Unity play Daniele.

Comment: I noticed that going to Unity play I didn't really upload my project, I can only play from my pc.

Comment: Yeah mine are unplayable as well it gets stuck at 90%. And because I attempted several times I have many broken duplicates on my accout I have not figured out how to delete. But ay least I got credit for the upload in the essentials course.

Answer (score -1):

I think that they had a problem with the server for a couple of days, cause today I uploaded that with no problems. You can try and play and hope have funny: https://play.unity.com/mg/other/webgl-builds-175577